# How to get active route snapshot onpopstate event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

According to the `ActivatedRoute` Interfaces docs `activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams` gives

> The current snapshot of this route

But it's giving me the wrong result or I'm missing something here.

`window.location.hash` gives => `#url + ?page=1` and `window.location.search` gives an empty string.

```
const popStateEvent$ = fromEvent(window, 'popstate');
this.subscribePopStateEvent = popStateEvent$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(this._activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams);
  callSomeFunctionHere(); // with exact query parameters
});
```

One possible solution for this might be subscribe to;

```
const activeRouteSubscribe = this._activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {});
```

And then unsubscribe;

```
activeRouteSubscribe.unsubscribe();
```

Surprisingly, this also doesn't work unless I take inside a setTimeOut function;

```
queryParamsEventHandler() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.queryParams = this.queryParamsFilterService.onPopState(this.queryParams);
    callSomeFunctionHere();
  }, 0);
}
```

I don't believe that is a good solution and I'm looking for a help to implement best practice as well as understand the concept. It is also doesn't call the `callSomeFunctionHere();` in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot` doesn't give you the updated value. `ActivatedRoute` has a `queryParams` `BehaviourSubject` which can be `subscribe`d to, to get the updated `queryParams`.

Instead of using:

```
this._activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams
```

Use:

```
this._activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: How do you get the updated value? If I subscribe to params I get previous and updated values. In the case, unsubscribe I get the previous value.

Comment: `subscribe`ing to `queryParams` on `ActivatedRoute` is supposed to give you the updated queryParams. And you'd be `unsubscribe`ing to it in the `ngOnDestroy` when it's not really required. I didn't clearly get what you're trying to achieve here though. A [simple minimal StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating your issue would really help.

Comment: I have finally found. As you said, queryParams gives the current value but in my application I was updating the some parameter multiple times so that gives multiple values.